# Using .live() for iFrame.load() event?

Tags: javascript, iframe, live, jquery

I know an iFrame is added to my page via javascript somewhere in my page, I want to be notified when it is loaded, but this doesn't work:

```
$("iframe").live("load",
    function () {
        alert(this.name + ": Im loaded!");
    });
```

No alert is shown
Any idea why? any idea how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do a callback after adding the iframe to your page.
As mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), it's not possible to bind live() to iframe load().

> Note: The .live() and .delegate() methods cannot be used to detect the
>   load event of an iframe. The load event does not correctly bubble up
>   the parent document and the  event.target isn't set by Firefox, IE9 or
>   Chrome, which is required to do event delegation.

So in your callback, you have to call this, maybe set a timeout to make sure it fires after the iframe has been loaded.

```
$("iframe").load(function () {
    alert(this.name + ": Im loaded!");
});
```

Comment: +1 for the tip that this is not possible. but your proposed solution is not applicable, otherwise I wouldn't try to use live()! I'll try to find a workaround. thnx

Comment: I see, sadly live or delegate doesn't work yet for iframe load event.

Answer (score -1):

It won't work, for *load* event only works on Window object.

If you wish to be noticed when page inside the iframe is loaded, then you should write code on the **inside page**, which calls *window.parent* to notify its parent page.

Comment: wrong! .load() works for any DOM element with "src" behavious, i.e. iFrame, window, img, etc.

Comment: You want to be noticed when the inner **page** is loaded，not the **iframe** itself, right? That is why it won't work.